# Mutable state update in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-state-management

For example, we have a state defined like this which is having some todos and we want to change done of that todo if they are completed

```
this.state = {
  // store an array of todo objects
  todos: [
    { task: 'do the dishes', done: false, id: 1 },
    { task: 'vacuum the floor', done: true, id: 2 }
  ]
};
```

For that, we can do this away.

```
  const theTodo = this.state.todos.find(t => t.id === id);
  theTodo.done = true; // NOOOOO

  this.setState({
    todos: this.state.todos
  });
```

}

But I am a little confused that find method on the array will return us the element which matches the condition inside it and we store it in a different variable and then access done to change it to true.
But still, we haven't changed the original state value as this was a copy one.

Then how come we can use this to save it?

```
 this.setState({
    todos: this.state.todos // bad
  });
```

Comment: Just because you "store it in a different variable," it doesn't mean that it's a different object, it still references that same object. Also, there's nothing preventing you from doing `this.setState({ this.state.todos })`, however, that's a bad practice and you shouldn't be mutation your `state` properties (your `todos` array, not the `object`s stored within that array). What you're doing might work right now, but it could break in the future because `React` doesn't handle this type of use case properly.

Answer (score 5):

The reason the code works is because [State Updates are Merged](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-are-merged).

> When you call `setState()`, **React merges the object you provide into the current state**.

But, it is just a **bad practice** [You shouldn't mutate `this.state` directly](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state).

> Never mutate `this.state` directly, as calling `setState()` afterwards **may replace the mutation you made**. Treat `this.state` as if it were immutable.

For completeness, just [pass a function](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#what-is-the-difference-between-passing-an-object-or-a-function-in-setstate) to `this.setState` and use `map` to save the immutablillity rule.

> Passing an update function allows you to access the current state value inside the updater.

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
  const todos = prevState.todos.map((todo) =>
    todo.id === id ? { ...todo, done: true } : todo
  );
  return { todos };
});
```

Comment: Btw, it's ok to mutate objects within the array but not the array itself, correct?

Comment: It still considered a bad practice, mutating the object inside the array still may lead to stale state.

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: If you have a state `[{id:1}]` and you mutate `id=2`, someone can read `this.state` while believing he got `id===1`.

Comment: @DennisVash Hi, could you please explain more, I still can not compare the difference between `your way` and `create spread object first then change the content`

Answer (score 0):

Just [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) everything

```js
this.setState(oldState => {
  const todos = oldState.todos;
  const todoIndex = todos.findIndex(pr => pr.id === id);
  const todo = todos[todoIndex];
  const newTodos = [...todos.slice(0, todoIndex), {...todo, done: true}, ...todos.slice(todoIndex + 1)]

  return {
    ...oldState,
    todos
  }
});
```

Comment: better explain your choice, why you need to do this way instead of mutate the object

Answer (score -3):

This is not an issue or something related to React framework. It's a basic understanding of JavaScript. Of course you will get a match, the find method is applicable to any array and your *todo* is an array. The find method returns a new object not a reference to it. If you want to update just that, create a copy of your todo, then use any method to update the right todo item, and then add the copied todo to the new state. You could use immer, or use spread operators, there's several ways to do this.

Comment: "The find method returns a new object not a reference to it, therefore returns an immutable object." - this is an incorrect statement. It returns the object that it finds and `JavaScript` objects are not immutable by default unless you make them such.